# UTC offset in minutes

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the difference between local time and UTC time in minutes (in C#)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [**`TimeZoneInfo`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx):

```
TimeSpan delta = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset();
double utcMinuteOffset = delta.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: `GetUtcOffset(...)` takes a parameter, so it might help to include that in the example. Such as...

`TimeSpan utcOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 7):

This should give you what you need.

```
(DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
```

Also you may find the `.ToUniversalTime` DateTime function of use.

Comment: I think you have the values reversed, should be (DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes;

Answer (score 6):

Yet another version:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Write((DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this MSDN artice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) for the full details.
The code sample at the end of the article expressly gives code to get the difference between local and UTC time.

For those that don't want to click the link here is an extract from that code:

```
  // Find difference between Date.Now and Date.UtcNow
  date1 = DateTime.Now;
  date2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
  difference = date1 - date2;
  Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", date1, date2, difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime localDt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utcDt = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeSpan localUtcDiff = utcDt.Subtract(localDt);
Console.WriteLine("The difference in minutes between local time and UTC time is " + localUtcDiff.TotalMinutes.ToString());
```