# TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm using TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone to get user's time offset from UTC like so:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
TimeSpan offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
return offset.Hours*60+offset.Minutes;
```

This works when I build for Android,iOS,Blackberry, but on WM8 I get the following build error:

Error: the 'System.TimeZone' doesn't exist in the target framework. I know the target framework is a subset of ASP.NET 2.0

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of getting UTC offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TimeZoneInfo` and its `GetUtcOffset(DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) are supported in .NET for Windows Store Apps.

So you may just do:

```
TimeSpan delta = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset();
double offset = delta.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here:

[UTC offset in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993654/utc-offset-in-minutes)

not the accepted answer but this:

```
 (DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
```